# Diese meine Katze / diese Katze von mir

Tags: grammaticality

Ist beides korrekt? Welcher Satz ist besser?

1. Diese meine Katze ist fügsam.
2. Diese Katze von mir ist fügsam.

Comment: 3) Meine Katze ist zutraulich/anhänglich/gehorsam/zahm/... (außer du hast viele Katzen)

Answer (score 4):

Beide Sätze sind korrekt. *diese Katze von mir* ist jedoch weniger idiomatisch.

*diese meine Katze* ist idiomatisch. Diese Formulierung ist allerdings selten und nicht besonders gebräuchlich. Es wirkt etwas gestelzt, weil die Bedeutung "diese Katze, welche meine ist" in den meisten Fällen einfacher durch *meine Katze* ausgedrückt werden kann.

Answer (score 1):

As Hubert notes, it is indeed unnatural* to have two determiners, so "Diese meine Katze" is definitely strange. But "Diese Katze von mir" is indeed grammatical, and is for me natural to use for example in

> Ich habe eine Katze. Diese Katze von mir ist sehr lieb.

where "von mir" only serves as additional information. Continuing with "Meine Katze" sounds strange to me here. It sounds like spoken German through, and so you have the usual dialectal differences.
But the construction is common, see the [DWDS corpus](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=Diese+%23%3D1+von+mir&corpus=kern) for "Diese * von mir" (not all matches are correct, as usual).

If you want to stack determiners, you can do so using genitive:

> Diese meiner Katzen ist fügsam.

singles out a single of your cats, while

> Meine dieser Katzen ist fügsam.

singles out your cat from a set of cats that are not yours.

*: There are [occurences in the DWDS corpus](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=Diese+%23%3D1+von+mir&corpus=kern) though, although all relatively old, like

> Ich bitte, diesen meinen Protest zu Protokoll zu nehmen. (Die Zeit, 21.10.1999, Nr. 43 )

Comment: 1999 isn't old. Quite popular are *diese meine Meinung, Ansicht, Überzeugung* and similar.

Answer (score -3):

Richtig sind diese Sätze:

> Diese Katze ist gehorsam.
> Meine Katze ist gehorsam.

Das Adjektiv *»fügsam«* beschreibt eine Wesen (meist eine Person, hier ein Tier), dass gegen Gewalt oder Gewaltandrohung keinen Widerstand mehr leistet und das tut, was man ihm aufzwingt. Wenn sich jemand fügt, dann nur, weil es jemanden anderen gibt, der seinen Willen durchsetzt, ohne Rücksicht auf die Betroffenen zu nehmen. Man verwendet dieses Wort daher nur, wenn es eine dominante Person gibt, die Macht auf jemanden ausübt, der eigentlich etwas anderes will. Die Person, die sich fügt, (oder hier: das Tier, das sich fügt) tut dies aus Angst.

Wenn man dieses Wort für ein Haustier verwendet, entsteht der Eindruck, dass das Tier bereits so große Angst vor seinem Halter hat, dass es aus Angst vor Schlägen oder anderen Arten der Bestrafung tut was man verlangt.

Will man hingegen ganz neutral ausdrücken, dass die Katze den Anweisungen ihres Besitzers folgt, dann nennt man die Katze *gehorsam* oder *gelehrig.*

---

Wenn man *»diese«* und *»meine«* zugleich auf dasselbe Substantiv anwendet, dann hat man zwei [Determinative](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)) für dieselbe Sache. Die Sache ist dann überbestimmt. Das ist in der deutschen Grammatik nicht vorgesehen, und deutsche Muttersprachler bilden auch keine Sätze, in denen mehrere Determinative eine einzige Sache mehrfach bestimmen.

---

> Diese Katze von mir ist gehorsam.

Auch in diesem Satz ist die Katze durch ein Demonstrativpronomen und ein Possessivattribut überbestimmt.

Wenn ein Possessivattribut eine Präpositionalgruppe ist, deren Kern ein Personalpronomen ist (*»von uns«, »von dir«, ...*), dann kann dieses Possessivattribut durch ein Possessivpronomen ersetzt werden:

> von uns → unser
> von dir → dein
> von mir → mein
> ...

Dann wird aber aus *»diese Katze von mir«* wieder *»diese meine Katze«,* und dass das ungrammatikalisch ist, habe ich oben bereits dargestellt.

---

Manchmal möchte man ein Demonstrativpronomen verwenden (z.B. weil man gerade mit einem Finger auf eine von mehreren Katzen zeigt) und möchte gleichzeitig den Besitzer der Katze nennen (z.B. weil unter den vielen Katzen nur einige wenige dem Sprecher gehören). Dann kann man das so machen:

> Diese Katze gehört mir. Sie ist gehorsam.
> Diese Katze gehört mir und sie ist gehorsam.

Comment: Zu. "... deutsche Muttersprachler bilden auch keine Sätze, in denen mehrere Determinative eine einzige Sache mehrfach bestimmen.". Eine der Lieblingsformulierungen des früheren deutschen Bundeskanzlers Kohl war "in diesem unserem Lande".  https://www.welt.de/kultur/article166145036/Wie-Helmut-Kohl-diese-unsere-Sprache-praegte.html

Comment: @HalvarF: Sagt sonst noch jemand so etwas? Mir ist nichts bekannt. Ausnahmen gibt es immer.

Comment: Ich verstehe fügsam nicht automatisch als durch Angst motiviert oder gar gebrochen. Ja, da kann gerade bei Katzen ein etwa schwieriger Begriff sein (da reichlich eigener Wille durchaus schon fast klischeehaft eine Eigenart von Katze sein kann), dennoch ist mein eigener Kater zumindest bei manchen Familienmitgliedern ausgesprochen fügsam auch bei ihm eher unangenehmen Dingen wie Wundversorgung oder Zecke entfernen, weil er uns vertraut und nicht, weil wir ihn mit Gewalt gefügig (jaja, Wortverwandschaft und so) gemacht haben. Beim Einsteigen in die Transportbox dagegen ist’s aus mit Fügsamkeit.

Comment: Wenn ich meine Katze als gelehrig bezeichne, beziehe ich das eher darauf, dass er einige Tricks gelernt hat (ja, er kann sich auf Stichwort hinsetzen oder ablegen oder Pfötchen geben - weil er das will und als Spiel versteht). Und gehorsam ist er auch, weil er manche Grenzen befolgt, also nicht auf den Tisch oder die Arbeitsfläche springt. Aber das sind andere Kontexte als Fügsamkeit.

Comment: An *diese meine* ist nichts ungrammatikalisch. Es wird damit nichts überbestimmt, wie du im letzten Absatz ja selbst feststellst. Es handelt sich sinnvollerweise um zwei unabhängige Eigenschaften, die von deutschen Muttersprachlern durchaus auf diese Weise bestimmt werden, auch wenn dir das nicht bekannt ist. Deine Ausführungen zu *fügsam* vs. *gehorsam* halte ich für abwegig. Siehe auch [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/f%C3%BCgsam). -1

Comment: Ich überspringe die Ausführungen zu Theorie und Praxis der Haustierhaltung und komme direkt zu der grammatikalischen Einsicht, daß zwischen dem Demonstrativpronomen "dies" und dem Possessivpronomen "mein" wohl ein Bedeutungsunterschied existieren muß, weil ansonsten entweder die eine oder die andere Wortart überflüssig wäre. Daß sie es beide nicht sind, ist wohl ein deutliches Indiz dafür, das keinerlei "Überbestimmung" vorliegt. Merken Sie sich diese (nämlich: die hier geschriebenen), meine (weil ich und niemand anderer sie geschrieben habe) Worte!